# Why are Jones vectors normalized?

Tags: optics, polarization

I have been studying polarization of light, and everywhere I look, one of the main approaches for dealing with polarization of light is by using Jones Vectors.

These vectors describe the polarization state of light in terms of two components, as in

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{E_{45}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

being a combination of

$$
\begin{align}
  \vec{E_{h}} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \quad
  \vec{E_{v}} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

However, I cannot find anywhere an explanation to:

1. *Why* are these vectors normalized
2. *How* are they normalized

I get that using normalized vectors may make things more convenient, and I could accept that, but I fail to see where is that $\sqrt{2}$ coming from.

---

*Clarification*: yes, I know the $\sqrt{2}$ factor comes from the normalization. But I can't find a way to derive this from the original expression for the wave:

$$ 
\vec{E} = E_{0}(\cos(\phi)\hat{\imath}+\sin(\phi)\hat{\jmath})
$$

That's something that even Hecht only mentions but doesn't show.

Comment: How long is the diagonal of a unit square?

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer since I managed to work it out.

One can write the electric field as

$$
\vec{E} = \mathfrak{Re}{\widetilde{E}}
$$

where

$$
\widetilde{E} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    E_{0_{x}}e^{i\phi_{x}}\\
    E_{0_{y}}e^{i\phi_{y}}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

For circularly polarized light, $E_{0_{x}} = E_{0_{y}} = E_{0}$ and $\phi_{y} = \phi_{x} - \frac{\pi}{2}$. We call $\phi_{x} = \phi$ for simplicity and

$$
\widetilde{E} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    E_{0}e^{i\phi}\\
    E_{0}e^{i(\phi-\frac{\pi}{2})}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  = E_{0}e^{i\phi}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
  \end{pmatrix}
  = E_{0}e^{i\phi}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    -i\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

the modulus of which is $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore, one can write $\widetilde{E}$ as

$$
\widetilde{E} = E_{0}e^{i\phi}\sqrt{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
 \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so

$$
\frac{\widetilde{E}}{\sqrt{2}E_{0}e^{i\phi}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  -i\\
\end{pmatrix}
= \widetilde{E}_{\mathfrak{R}}
$$

which is the Jones Vector for right-circular polarized light.

---

Hecht drops a hint at this but doesn't actually work it out, so I had to take that last step. I hope this helps someone who comes across it in the future.